# How to use jsoup for making a loop in URL to request data parameters?

Tags: android, performance, jsoup

How to use jsoup for making a loop in URL to request data parameters?

The loop I made take long time.

for example

```
static String[] cValues = {"AED", "AFN", "ALL", "AMD", "ANG","AOA","ARS","AUD","AZN","BBD","BDT","BGN","BHD","BIF"};


            for(int i=0;i<cValues.length;i++){
            for(int y=0;y<cValues.length;y++) {


                    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.zzz.com/finance/converter?a=1&from="+cValues[i]+"&to="+cValues[y]+"").get();

                    Element m = doc.select("div#zzz").first();


                System.out.println(cValues[i] + "-" + cValues[y] + m.child(0).text());

}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a sequential programming approach, as a result you code execution stuck for each request and resume when the response is received. Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for each Jsoup request.

See this [example](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/), this example use AsyncTask with the Jsoup.